# Can we locate Google Cloud Speech API server?

Tags: cloud, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I have a VM instance in Singapore. I need to make sure that speech-to-text requests from my instance are sent to the nearest API server in order to gain 
the highest throughput. I have read their document but I still can't find the answer. The relevant one that I found is this link: https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?region=asia-pacific#region.  The  Speech API is not checked in all regions including USA and Europe but it has a superscript '1'. The meaning of the superscript is shown in this picture.
[image]

So from my understanding, there are servers located in every region (if i'm wrong, please tell me). How to make sure that my requests are sent within Singapore. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/) you provided, the **Speech-To-Text API** is a shared tool that runs overall all the GCP infrastructure in order to guarantee the availability of the services; therefore, it is not possible to select the servers where the request will be executed, which means that your request can be processed by using any of the multiple servers available on the different regions in a global location base.